# A coordinated app install already exists for

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, macos

I'm trying to run react-native app on Mac(designed for iPad), but it's not working. Everything works fine on iOS. I deleted the application from the iOS simulator and deleted DerivedData, but this does not help.
(rn version 0.71.7, mac os m1 pro)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Installed the application from the appstore, then deleted it using cleaner and it works